# Instagram photo display

Tags: php, instagram

I have been using this code on my website for an instagram feed and suddenly itis not working anymore, I have created a new id and accesstoken but these are not working either.

```
<?php
    // Supply a user id and an access token
    $userid = "******";
    $accessToken = "*******";

    // Gets our data
    function fetchData($url){
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch); 
         return $result;
    }

    // Pulls and parses data.
    $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}   /media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}");
    $result = json_decode($result);
?>


    <?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
    <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution,   high_resolution) -->
    <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instagram has updated their TOS. Each application needs to be reviewed by them now.